# Angular: Can content of an HTML attribute accessed from within the same HTML tag?

Tags: html, angular

**This question is an Angular specific.**

I am writing an Angular program and in my template (html) I need to read the content of **id**' attribute, from within the *same tag*.

Below is a very simplified example that checks if **id**  has a value named 'good', and then assigns **class** a value named 'active'.

```
 <li id="good" [className]=" [id] == 'good' ? 'active' : '' "><li>
```

This is not working. Could you please tell me how you could do this in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three ways to achieve the same goal.

1. Use ts variable

```html
<li [id]="id" 
    [className]="id == 'good' ? 'active' : '' ">
    Use ts variable
</li>
```

2. Use template reference variable

```html
<li id="good" 
    #li
    [className]=" li.id == 'good' ? 'active' : '' ">
    Use template reference variable
</li>
```

3. Use css selector

```html
<li id="good" class="good-css" >
    Use css selector
</li>
```

```css
.good-css[id=good] {
  color: blue
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anowbm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Hope to help you.

Comment: It's Working!!! Thanks Hsuan Lee. All three answers are working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

Typescript:

```
id = 'good'
```

Template:

```
<li [id]="id" 
    [class]="id == 'good' ? 'active' : '' ">
<li>
```

Comment: Thanks to you Adrita Sharma for helping. Your solution is also working.